# Openlayers unable to vertically scroll page when touch and dragging the map

Tags: angular, scroll, openlayers

I am using **Openlayers** with **Angular**, and have embedded a simple map on the screen. I have disabled **interactions** like so:

```
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  interactions: [],
  layers: [this.layer],
  view: this.view
});
```

This prevents the map from panning when it is touched & dragged, which is what I need. However, I would like to be able to vertically scroll the browser page  down by pressing & dragging the map so the user is able to see content below the map. At the moment, it is only possible to scroll the page by touching & dragging an area outside of the map.

There are github issues relating to this:
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6767
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8458

But I could not get it to work. Anyone able to help with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. My preferred way is to configure the map with

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import {defaults as defaultInteractions} from 'ol/interaction';

new Map({
  target: 'map',
  interactions: defaultInteractions({
    onFocusOnly: true
  }),
  // ...
});
```

The target element for the map in the markup needs to have a `tabindex` attribute, e.g.

```
<div tabindex="1" id="map"></div>
```

You can see that in action here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/interaction-options.html. The idea is that as long as the map does not have the focus, you can pan and scroll the page. Only when it has the focus (e.g. after a click on the map), pan and scroll gestures will modify the map view.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. 
Unfortunately I already tried that. You mentioned the above suggestion in the github threads I linked to in my question.

It does not work on a mobile device. If you touch the map and try to drag the screen, it doesn't move.
The link you posted ( https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/interaction-options.html) also demonstrates this "not working" on a mobile device unfortunately.

Comment: Ok you're right. Looks like something must have changed in the meantime, because I had tested it back then on touch devices.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. I will check it again on the next release of OpenLayers

Comment: Hi @ahocevar - I have just tried with the latest openlayers library release 6.0.1 in my project. Unfortunately, page scrolling by dragging the map still does not work. I have also tried pointing a mobile browser at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/interaction-options.html and it does not work there either. Could the fix you made with pull-request https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/9634 perhaps been undone by another later pull-request? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You're right, this has been broken again. See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/10187 for a new fix.

Comment: Hi @ahocevar - Have just updated to latest version of openlayers (v6.1.1) and the swipe to scroll works on mobile browser now. Thank you so much for your fix and support.