# Unable to scroll page with OpenLayers map on mobile device

Tags: scroll, touch, openlayers, drag

I have a page with OpenLayers map in my Cordova mobile application. It looks like OpenLayers catch the drag event, so it's not possible to scroll the page when user touches the map ( it works only when drag event starts outside the map ). I have found couple of similar questions here (e.g. [Openlayers unable to vertically scroll page when touch and dragging the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353094/openlayers-unable-to-vertically-scroll-page-when-touch-and-dragging-the-map)). So my code looks like this right now:

HTML:

```
<div id="map" tabindex="1"></div>
```

JS:

```
var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({ 
  onFocusOnly: true, 
  altShiftDragRotate: false, 
  pinchRotate: false, 
  doubleClickZoom: false, 
  pinchZoom: false, 
  dragZoom: false, 
  dragPan: false, 
  dragRotate: false, 
  mouseWheelZoom: false 
});

new ol.Map({
    target: "map"
    interactions: interactions,
    layers: [],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([15.523, 49.718], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 8,
        minZoom: 7,
        maxZoom: 18
    })
});
```

Unfortnately, it's not possible to scroll the page event with this code.

Comment: Which version of OpenLayers are you using?  The `onFocusOnly` option wasn't available before version 5 and the comments in your link reference a bug which has only recently been fixed for version 6 beta.

Comment: I have version 5.3

Comment: Does this example work on your device as expected? https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/interaction-options.html

Comment: No, it is the same issue - the page scrolls only when I start drag outside the map region

Comment: OK, so as well as the interactions only working when the map has focus you will also need to prevent the map having focus.  The usual way to stop an element having focus is  `document.getElementById("map").onfocus = function() { this.blur(); };`